# Seemingly innocuous first order differential equation which involves $Si(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $x\frac{dy}{dx}-7y=4x^2\cos(x)$. I would like to find the general solution.

My attempt:  Divide through by $x$ to obtain $\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{7}{x}y=4x\cos(x)$. This has integrating factor $\frac{1}{x^7}$. Multiplying through gives us $y=4x^7\int\frac{\cos(x)}{x^6}dx$. However this is not integrable using elementary functions. As such I went through the whole $Si(x)$ argument, and my final answer was:

$$y=-\frac{1}{30}x^7Si(x)-\frac{1}{30}(x^2-6)x^3\sin(x)-\frac{1}{30}x^2\cos(x)(x^4-2x^2+24)$$

Is this correct? Any advice would be greatly appreciated:)

I tried substituting in this form for $y$ into WolframAlpha, and then wrote the LHS of the original differential equation (to see if LHS=RHS) but it was not understood by WA so Id appreciate if someone could explain how to verify this.

Comment: There were no IC's - clearly I made the most rookie calculus mistake ever and forgot to include it:/ glad it looks correct though! It was so messy I couldn't consider verifying LHS=RHS

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to explicitly do this, I typed in $y=...$ and then the LHS but it doesn't seem to interpret this

Comment: Just done it:))

Comment: Why the tag "partial-differential-equations" ? I see no PDE in your question.